# R lsfit() and Numpy lstsq()

Tags: python, r, numpy, least-squares

I'm doing some math in numpy, and in R, and I think it should get the same result, but it does not, could you please explain why? And how can I mimick the result I get from numpy, in R?

NUMPY/PYTHON

```
>>> X
matrix([[ 1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0],
        [ 0, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1],
        [ 0, -1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -1],
        [ 0,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0]])
>>> y
matrix([[500],
        [300],
        [600],
        [250],
        [400],
        [350]])
>>> linalg.lstsq(X,y)[0]
matrix([[ 316.66666667],
        [-133.33333333],
        [ 150.        ],
        [-200.        ],
        [ 133.33333333],
        [-266.66666667]])
```

R

```
> X
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0   -1    0    0
[2,]    0   -1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0   -1
[4,]    0   -1    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    0   -1
[6,]    0    0    0   -1    1    0

> y
     [,1]
[1,]  500
[2,]  300
[3,]  600
[4,]  250
[5,]  400
[6,]  350

> lsfit(X,y, intercept=FALSE)$coef
       X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6 
583.33333 133.33333 416.66667  66.66667 400.00000   0.00000 
Warning message:
In lsfit(X, y, intercept = FALSE) : 'X' matrix was collinear
```

Comment: Do you always ignore warnings?

Comment: If you compute both squared errors, you will find they are equal (`1666.667`). R is telling you your matrix is collinear so there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: how do i get the answer i got in python, in r?

Comment: what makes you like this one in particular?

Comment: the answer makes sense to me.  the matrix is modeled on the idea that 2 rows represent a football game.  the first row, in the pair, has one team's offense (positive 1), versus a teams defense (negative 1), and the y value is the total yards the offense gained.  the second row, in the pair, is the reverse of that.

okay i now see that 583 - 66 = 517 and 316 - ( -200) is 516, so its the same thing.  thanks for helping me to see what is going on.

Comment: In general, R and Numpy might give you different answers because Numpy's `lstsq` uses the SVD (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1859) while R uses the QR decomposition. These can behave differently, especially when the matrix is ill-conditioned like this.